# Pods unable instal or update

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I've opened my 1 month old project and when I try to build it showing me error.

> error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

and when I try to install 'pod install' or update 'pod update it shows me following error.

> [!] Oh no, an error occurred.
>
> Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
>   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=%5B%21%5D+Xcodeproj+doesn%27t+know+about+the+following+attributes+%7B%22inputFileListPaths%22%3D%3E%5B%5D%2C+%22outputFileListPaths%22%3D%3E%5B%5D%7D+for+the+%27PBXShellScriptBuildPhase%27+isa.%0AIf+this+attribute+was+generated+by+Xcode+please+file+an+issue%3A+https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FCocoaPods%2FXcodeproj%2Fissues%2Fnew&type=Issues
>
> If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above,
>   on: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new
>
> Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to
>   properly submit a ticket:
>   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

as shown following screenshot
[image]

What I've done

- Delete Drive Data
- Close xcode, restart system
- Delete pods 'deintegrate pod'
- But When I hit command 'pod install' it give me error.

Kindly help me where is issue and how to fix this.
Thanks

Comment: `pod update --verbose`? Else, I'd remove the `podfile.lock` (make a copy just in case). But to help your get an answer, copy/paste the (full) output instead of only a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to update Ruby using Homebrew- https://brew.sh, this package manager comes out useful in many cases, after you installed it you can run `brew install ruby` in terminal in order to install the latest ruby version.

Here's what Ruby wrote:

> Homebrew is a commonly used package manager on macOS. Installing a Ruby using Homebrew is easy: `brew install ruby` This should install the latest Ruby version.

Source: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/

Comment: Thanks but it return response "-bash: brew: command not found"
I hit "brew install ruby"

Comment: You should also install Homebrew for that, there are more ways to install ruby but Homebrew is really useful in a lot of cases, take a look on their website- https://brew.sh